# How to retrieve the companion object from the type

Tags: scala

I want to write a generic method and I need to retrieve the companion object (especially the `apply` method) from the type.

[update] `X` is a case class, so the companion object has an apply method.

Ex : `def f[X]() = X.apply("42")`

Comment: Is X completely generic? If it's a collection, then the `.companion` method is implemented in `GenTraversable`

Comment: as updated, `X` is a case class

Comment: Then Eugene's 2nd answer applies?

Comment: yes, but implicits are cumbersome …

Answer (score 2):

There is no generic solution, also nothing restrict companion object to have apply method. It can be companion without apply. I would suggest to use type class pattern in this case.

```
  trait CompanionWithApply[T] {
    def apply(s: String): T
  }

  class X(s: String)
  object X extends CompanionWithApply[X] {
    def apply(s: String): X = new X(s)
  }

  class Y(s: String)
  object Y extends CompanionWithApply[Y]{
    def apply(s: String): Y = new Y(s)
  }

  implicit val XCompanion = X
  implicit val YCompanion = Y

  def f[T: CompanionWithApply] = implicitly[CompanionWithApply[T]].apply("42")

  println(f[X])
  println(f[Y])
```

Comment: nice, but if X and Y are case classes, we need to duplicate the apply method…

Comment: You don´t need to introduce `implicit val`s. Just use `implicit` as a modifier for `object`.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution that is much smaller, but you X,Y has to be case class

```
  case class X(s: String)
  case class Y(s: String)

  implicit def xConstruct = X
  implicit def yConstruct = Y

  def f[T](implicit construct: (String) => T) = construct("abc")

  println(f[X])
  println(f[Y])
```

Comment: Is there a way to avoid declaring implicits ?